# How do I get rid of this syntax error that keeps appearing no matter what I do?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am attempting to recreate a machine learning example on google colab using  datasets different to the one used in the example. I have a cell that is giving me an invalid syntax error.

This is the code:

```
# Mean and Std from ImageNet
NORM_MEAN = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
NORM_STD = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
# No resizing and center crop necessary as images are already preprocessed.
plain_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=NORM_MEAN,
                         std=NORM_STD)
])

# Load dataset and create data loader
imagenet_path = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, "Train/")
assert os.path.isdir(imagenet_path), f"Could not find the ImageNet dataset at expected path \"{imagenet_path}\". " + \
                                     f"Please make sure to have downloaded the ImageNet dataset here, or change the {DATASET_PATH=} variable."
dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=imagenet_path, transform=plain_transforms)
data_loader = data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, drop_last=False, num_workers=8)

# Load label names to interpret the label numbers 0 to 999
with open(os.path.join(imagenet_path, "label_list.json"), "r") as f:
    label_names = json.load(f)

def get_label_index(lab_str):
    assert lab_str in label_names, f"Label \"{lab_str}\" not found. Check the spelling of the class."
    return label_names.index(lab_str)
```

And the error reads:

```
File "<fstring>", line 1
    (DATASET_PATH=)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can't figure out where the syntax problem is and I have no error on any of my previous cells. Can anyone provide any guidance?

I've tried retyping, spacing, and joining the divided line into one line but haven't been able to get rid of the error yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the = in there

Comment: Thanks, good news, that good rid of the error. The bad news is that it created another one I now have to solve. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid syntax added in Python 3.8:

> [f-strings support = for self-documenting expressions and debugging](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging).
>
> ... An f-string such as `f'{expr=}'` will expand to the text of the expression, an equal sign, then the representation of the evaluated expression...

If using <3.8 it is a syntax error.

Demonstration:

```py
>>> DEBUG_PATH="some string"
>>> print(f'{DEBUG_PATH=}')
DEBUG_PATH='some string'
```

You can use the following pre-3.8 for the same output.  You can see it is a bit redundant:

```py
>>> print(f'DEBUG_PATH={DEBUG_PATH!r}')
DEBUG_PATH='some string'
```

Comment: This is cool! Thank you for sharing. Is this only for f-strings though? I can't seem to find other use cases